# Regex expression on UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c

Hi is it possible to apply regex expression on UISearchBar ?

Comment: Yes, of course it is via `range(of:options:)`

Comment: In which method??

Comment: In `filter(by: {})`

Comment: @VADIAN: thank you.

Comment: Ya i got the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution for my problem.

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    NSString *regex=@"[0-9]";
    NSPredicate *validation = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];

    if(searchBar.text.length>5){
        if(range.length == 1)
            return YES;
        else
            return NO;
    }else{

        if([validation evaluateWithObject:text]){
            return YES;
        }else{
            if(range.length == 1)
                return YES;
            else
                return NO;
        }
    }
}
```

It  helps to to restrict number of characters in a search-bar and only allows numbers.